# Xamarin.Android Azure build fails for MSBuild 17

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I've a Xamarin.Forms application with an Azure build pipeline running on a macos-12 agent that we use to generate the .apk file to deploy to Google play store. The Azure pipeline is using the Xamarin.Android task with below Yaml.

```
steps:
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  displayName: '$(PackageName) - Building Droid'
  inputs:
    projectFile: Droid/MySample.Droid.csproj
    configuration: 'Release'
    clean: true
    msbuildVersionOption: 15.0
    jdkVersionOption: 1.11
```

But this fails with below error if I change **msbuildVersionOption: 17.0**. Any help is appreciated.

##[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/xbuild' failed with exit code 1

Errors:

/Users/runner/work/1/s/Droid/MySample.Droid.csproj: error : /Users/runner/work/1/s/Droid/MySample.Droid.csproj: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /Users/runner/work/1/s/Droid/MySample.Droid.csproj: Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets: Xamarin.Android.AvailableItems.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: The attribute "TfmSpecificPackageFile" in element <"None> is unrecognized.

Comment: The [latest Stable Mono release](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) is 6.12.0 and the version of MSBuild in that release is v16.10. If you set the `msbuildVersionOption` to 16.0, is the error resolved?

Comment: No, setting MSBuild version 16.0 also fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having compared with the software version installed on different [MS-hosted agent images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) and based on your requriement to use `msbuildVersionOption: 17.0`, you should opt to build your Xamarin app on MS-hosted agent with the image of `windows-2022` as suggested in [Build Xamarin apps - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

If it is required to build your app on macOS agent, you may consider filing a GitHub issue by choosing the `Included Software links` in the [Use a Microsoft-hosted agent table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software). Or, you can also use a self-hosted agent that includes the exact versions of software that you need. For more information, see [Self-hosted macOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/osx-agent?view=azure-devops).

Comment: This is a an existing app which used to build in macos all the time for both iOS and Droid. However I see the option of building iOS on mac and Droid on windows from your links in separate agents so that it can run parallel too. I'll try that, thanks for the links.

Comment: I tried it on Windows agent and it has MSBuild 17.0 and I could successfully able to build an apk out of it. Thank you Alvin.